# How do I optimize this code involving counting without any libraries or modules?

Tags: python, optimization

This is part of a preparation exercise in a French coding contest I'm participating in (Algoréa). Once again, this isn't the real thing, just the warm-up exercise.

The program is supposed to receive a bunch of positions as integers, and needs to output greatest amount of time a position is passed. For example, 1 3 2 6 2 means you start at 1, then go to 3, passing by all the positions in between, then going back to 2, then 6, and so on. Here the output would be 4, as the second position has been passed 4 times.

```
def move(x1, x2, l):
    if x1 < x2:
        l.extend(range(x1, x2))
    else:
        l.extend(range(x2, x1))


positions = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    positions.append(int(input()))

p = [] # positions, but instead of finding [1, 3] you would find [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(m) - 1):
    move(m[i], m[i + 1], p)

result = [] # count how many times each space was passed
for i in range(max(m)):
    wall.append(result.count(i))

print(max(result))
```

This is easy, but to earn the maximum amount of points, you need to optimize the program as much as you can... This is where I'm stuck. I initially made it just increment the corresponding indexes in a list each time they were passed, but switched to counting each value at the end as you see here, thinking it might be faster, but it wasn't. I couldn't find any answers to this anywhere (the afore-mentioned preparation exercises are those from the real contest in 2018 so I thought I might been able to find something).

I can't use any libraries or modules, not even built-in ones, so I can only use `list.count()` as far as I'm aware.

Is there anything that sticks out here that could be done better? I understand that this question might be hard to answer.

Comment: Optimize how? - for lines of code? readability? memory usage? processing time? does your solution work?

Comment: I meant for processing time, sorry... And yes, this works, but not any faster, as far as I could tell.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the comment, I am not sure what you are trying to optimize for. However, your method uses (potentially) quadratic space, whereas linear is enough.  You need to keep an array of counts, and each move, instead of appending the range, just increments the indices covered by the range by one. Then you do a final scan to find the argmax.

Comment: I feel like I might be missing something here, but wouldn't that be quadratic as well?

Comment: @AmmarHijazi quadratic time, yes, quadratic space, no.

Comment: (you are just using an array of size `n`)

Answer (score 0):

Here, generate a list of each step and join them together. Build a dictionary with key-value pair from min to max position and their count. Finally, find the max count and it's position.

```py
a = [1, 3, 2, 6, 2]

items = []
for i in range(len(a)-1):
    items += list(range(*sorted(a[i:i+2])))
result = {i:items.count(i) for i in range(min(items), max(items)+1)}

print(max(result.items(), key=lambda item:item[1]))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.